# How to read very long lines from the stdin prompt with python?

Tags: python

I'm having a problem reading very long lines (2500 characters) at the stdin prompt using python.
I've tried to use CMD, powershell, WSL.

I've tried to use:

input(),

sys.stdin.readline (),

for line in sys.stdin.

Everyone is cutting the lines to 510 characters when paste the text.

Has anyone had this problem?

Comment: is there a special reason to read it directly from the command line and not from a file?
you can just write the line to a file and read it from there.

Comment: What is "the stdin prompt"?  Your process has concepts of stdin and stdout, and very often those two streams are connected to a terminal, and often your program will write prompts to the terminal, and often that is accomplished by writing to stderr.   But it sounds like your problem is unrelated to python and more related to the mechanism by which you paste the text.

Comment: ```a=input(); print(len(a))``` with a string of length 2562 char copy and pasted into the stdin prompt:  ran as expected (prints 2562).  Using Python 3.6 under: Windows CMD, WSL in Wsttty.  1) make sure your copied text is really as long as you expect by pasting it into something else like Notepad; 2) I would look into limitations that your terminal might be imposing on copy-paste, 3) see if there are special characters in the copied string that might be interfering?

Comment: I am coding the problems of the judge on line, more specifically problem 183 for a research paper.
https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=119

Reading from a file works perfectly. But not accept no online judge.

I am limited to python 3.5.1 accepted by the judge.

Comment: I am using the fourth sample data entry from uDebug.
https://udebug.com/UVa/183

Comment: Hi guys, I found out what was going on. My vscode changed to the python 3.8.5 and I didn't see it.
I went back to 3.5.1 and it worked perfectly.
Either 3.8.5 includes this limitation, or has a bug.
Thank you for your help.